# Issues in attaching $scope.$watch to array items

Tags: angularjs

I'm unable to attach $watch to a variable to check its validity within a form.
fName.$valid throws error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exp' of undefined
at watchFnToHumanReadableString
```

Array : menuItems

```
{
          name : 'Games',
          validationRequired : true,
          formName : 'games_action'
}
```

JS

```
angular.forEach($scope.menuItems, function(item,i) {
        if(item.validationRequired) {
            var fName = item.formName;

            $scope.$watch(fName.$valid, function(validity) {   /* throws error */
                domeSomething(validity);
            })


        }    
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your template (HTML)?  How are you defining the form name in the template?

Comment: <form name="games_action" novalidate ng-controller="GameCtrl"></form>

Comment: If I write manually.. $scope.$watch('games_action.$valid', function(validity) {
         console.log(validity)
}) It works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its because fName is a String and has no own Property like `$valid`.
But watching the string `fName+'.$valid'` should be possible.

```
$scope.$watch(fName+'.$valid', function(validity) {
    console.log('$watcher triggered: ', validity);
})
```